# doubling time and closed loop bandwidth

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, pi-controller

I have a plant having a pair of real poles

$\lambda_1 = -7.5, \lambda_2 = 7.5$ and I want to derive the minimum closed-loop bandwidth required to properly control the plant.

By looking at the doubling time (Ref. Etkin, Reid, "Dynamics of Flight: Stability and Control", page 164), defined as

$\frac{\log(2)}{\max{Re(\lambda)}}$ I see that for my system the doubling time is 0.09 s.

How do I relate this value to the minimum required closed-loop bandwidth that my controller has to have?

Thanks!

Comment: For those who are interested: I found the answer by myself: the closed-loop bandwidth must be at least 2 times the largest eigenvalue. (ref. Skogestad & Postlewaith)